# C- Is it possible to change the printing and scanning order?

Tags: printf

printf("* What is your age: xxx  *)
scanf("%d", &age);

Is there a way I change the order the way it is executed. The xxx is the place i want the age to be inputed, but i want the * at the end to be printed before i am prompted to enter a number. Currently it asks for the number on the next line.

The output i would like to see is like the following:

*What is your age: (Input required)*

(Notice the * is already printed while i am prompted for an input in a field before the *)

Please can someone show me how to rewrite this?

Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: Sorry, the * was removed from the question above. This is how it was meant to look. (Astrix) What is your age: (Input required)(Astrix)

Comment: You probably want to use a library like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) if you need this level of sophistication in your screen appearance and cursor management.

Comment: Use ncurse http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy way to do this with a small problem. You can use your `printf` function in normal way.

`printf("* What is your age: xxx *");`

Since at this point the cursor is right side of last asterisk, you need to move it left side 5 time to bring it where the first `x` is.

If you are on Linux, `\033[<N>D` can be used to move cursor once to left.
(@ref http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html).

Once the cursor is on first x, you can use your `scanf` function to prompt for number. But there is probability that user enters more than 3 digits and that asterisk will be cleared which is a problem.